# How to re-write a function in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming

I am making a Mini lisp language. How can I re-write this using just arrows:

```
-- a comp expression is the comp operator and the parsing of two expressions
compExpr :: Parser Expr
compExpr = CompExpr <$> parseCompOp <*> parseExpr <*> parseExpr
```

For reference, here is what the other parsers are:

```
data CompOp = Eq | Lt deriving (Show, Eq)

-- define the expression types
data Expr
  = CompExpr CompOp Expr Expr
  deriving (Show, Eq)

parseCompOp :: Parser CompOp
parseCompOp =
  do parseKeyword "equal?" >> return Eq
    <|> do symbol "<" >> return Lt

-- the main parsing function which alternates between all the options you have
parseExpr :: Parser Expr
parseExpr =
  do
    parseAtom
    <|> parseParens compExpr
    <|> parseParens parseExpr

-- an atom is a literalExpr, which can be an actual literal or some other things
parseAtom :: Parser Expr
parseAtom =
  do
    literalExpr
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
compExpr :: Parser Expr
compExpr = do
  op <- parseCompOp
  expr1 <- parseExpr
  expr2 <- parseExpr
  return (CompExpr op expr1 expr2)
```

Since I am not sure how to test this, is this function equivalent to the first function I showed?

Comment: Yes, `f <$> x <*> y <*> z` is the same as `do {a <- x; b <- y; c <-z; return (f x y z)}`. But I'd usually rather write the former.

Comment: *If* your `Parser` is a law-abiding citizen, you can use the equations [`pure = return`, `fmap f x = pure f <*> x`, and `m1 <*> m2 = m1 >>= (\x1 -> m2 >>= (\x2 -> return (x1 x2)))`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Applicative) to prove they are equivalent. Might be a good exercise for you to try if the goal is learning about these concepts.